# nextjs index page route give /404 after next build

Tags: next.js, build, netlify, next.js13, next-router

my application is running on local all route is working perfectly but when i build the project it give the route error

$ npm run build

> restore-frontend@0.1.0 build
> next build && next export

Linting and checking validity of types  . ⨯ ESLint: Failed to load config "react-app" to extend from. Referenced from: C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\Restorationfront\package.json
✓ Linting and checking validity of types
✓ Creating an optimized production build
✓ Compiled successfully
✓ Collecting page data
Generating static pages (0/9)  [    ]/_next/static/media/Group.dc36ba5b.png
✓ Generating static pages (9/9)
✓ Finalizing page optimization

Route (pages)                              Size     First Load JS
┌ ○ / (397 ms)                             18.9 kB         102 kB
├   └ css/e7ee449c96cb7ce4.css             1.14 kB
├ ○ /404                                   181 B          83.2 kB
├ ○ /auth/login (321 ms)                   2.86 kB        85.9 kB
├ ○ /auth/signup (322 ms)                  3.05 kB        86.1 kB
├ ○ /PrivacyPolicy (353 ms)                4.23 kB        87.3 kB
├ ○ /profile (352 ms)                      2.26 kB        85.3 kB
├ ○ /restore/RestorePage (314 ms)          3.57 kB        86.6 kB
└ ○ /Termconduction (368 ms)               2.95 kB          86 kB

- First Load JS shared by all              83 kB
  ├ chunks/framework-b31dd959a3bdfd87.js   45.2 kB
  ├ chunks/main-dfb24f9b84bcc79a.js        36.8 kB
  ├ chunks/pages/_app-17d19c65739e24e7.js  195 B
  └ chunks/webpack-fd30e845e9427aeb.js     813 B

○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)

and after deployment the page return the blank page and other route is work perfectly if we add manually route to the URL

console error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysRVj.png)

repo folder structure img :
[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NE7Qu.png)

the page need to render after build